# rake not work on CommunityEngine Opensocial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, communityengine

I using rails 3.1.2 for now.

gem 'community_engine' => OK

bundle install --binstubs => OK

bin/rake community_engine:install:migrations

**rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Tag**

anyone can help me solved this problem? thanks a lot.

Comment: Very hard to answer this, there is a class missing sure, is there a file in app/models/tag.rb ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're running an older version of Community Engine.

In your *Gemfile* replace

```
gem 'community_engine'
```

with

```
gem 'community_engine' , :git => 'https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you need to write

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

in your Gemfile